# Titles too long for header

Tags: header-footer

I have the following document,  The problem is that when the chapter name is long, it is cut off when displayed in the header.  What can I do to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\usepackage{geometry}

\NewDocumentCommand \wvPage {}
%% 31x21 cm Page Size
{
    \geometry{ paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
        textwidth=12cm,  textheight=20cm,
        left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm, includehead}
}

\wvPage

\ExplSyntaxOff

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Ramanujan}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter {This is an introduction to some topic}
    
    \section{Test}
    
    Some text
    
    \subsection{A Subsection}
    
    More text here
    
    \subsubsection{A Subsubection}
    
    And more text
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have "over-specification" warnings being issued by [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) with this setup.

Answer (score 5):

The cheapest way to correct for this is to specify a shortened header for the long chapter title using `\chaptermark{<shortened title>}`. This is similar to using the optional argument to `\chapter[<ToC entry>]{<title>}` to display a different `ToC entry` to what is displayed in the main document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{geometry}

%% 13x21 cm Page Size
\geometry{ paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
  %textwidth=12cm,  textheight=20cm, % This is not needed
  margin=8mm, includehead}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{This is an introduction to some topic}
\chaptermark{Introduction}

\section{Test}\lipsum[1-10]

\subsection{A Subsection}\lipsum[11-20]

\subsubsection{A Subsubection}\lipsum[21-30]
    
\end{document}
```